# Add class on only 1 time for each class with addClass jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass

There is a value `( $btn_id )` and it gets any strings and multiple times on a page. (ex. $btn_id = "btn1", "btn2", "btn3" )

And I want to add these in a class (fp-slidesNav ). but the class has to be only 1 time on each fp-slidesNav. Code below-

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $( ".fp-slidesNav" ).addClass( "'. $btn_id .'" ); });</script>';`

However it added like "btn1 btn2 btn3" on all of fp_slidesNav-

`<script..> script..</script><div class="fp_slidesNav btn1 btn2 btn3">.......</div>
<script..> script..</script><div class="fp_slidesNav btn1 btn2 btn3">.......</div>
<script..> script..</script><div class="fp_slidesNav btn1 btn2 btn3">.......</div>`

This is what I want-

```
<script..> script..</script><div class="fp_slidesNav btn1">.......</div>
<script..> script..</script><div class="fp_slidesNav btn2">.......</div>
<script..> script..</script><div class="fp_slidesNav btn3">.......</div>
```

Please have a look at this screenshot. ( http://prntscr.com/cf3nwr )

As you may know, `$btn_id` is changing all the time and amount of this script as well.

Any tips?

I also tried .. "Closest" and "find". but no luck..

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $( ".fp-slidesNav" ).closest(".fp-section").addClass( "'. $btn_id .'" ); });</script>';`

It's also the same result.

Please advise me.

OK, I created this for better understand.. ( https://jsfiddle.net/phnsuusn/ )
So the color should be working for each.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

I assumed OP would know how to refactor the Snippet so it can pass a variable. So this update is just a simple modification of the Snippet so that it passes the value of `$btn` and assigns a unique class to each element (that part it already does).

***See below for Snippet 2***

## Update Continued Below

---

### Older Post

Use `.each` only once, it's like a loop on steroids. On each iteration, increment the className `btn`+suffix by 1:

```
var idx = i + 1;
$(this).addClass("btn" + idx);
```

#### [**<kbd>FIDDLE</kbd>**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/5nr9nj22/2/)

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
$(".fp_slidesNav").each(function(i) {
  var idx = i + 1;
  $(this).addClass("btn" + idx);
});
```

```css
.btn1 {
  color: red;
}
.btn2 {
  color: blue;
}
.btn3 {
  color: black;
}
.btn4 {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">Red color</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">Blue color</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">Black color</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">Gray color</div>
```

---

~~~~  END OF SNIPPET 1  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

---

## UPDATE CONTINUED

The critical parts of the update is as follows:

```
var $btn_id = ['btn', 'btn', 'btn', 'btn', 'any_string_is possible', 'section_first', 'session_2nd', 'part_3', 'etc', 'THIS_IS_THE_CORRECT_WAY'];
```

OP never specified how the value of `$btn_id` came to be or whence it came from. OP only stated that `$btn_id` constantly changes with no rhyme or reason. Nor did OP mention what type of data structure these unknown amount of strings were in. Are they in an object literal? JSON? Array? Map? Set? arguments? So I decided to use an array.

The other important part is:

```
  var ID = $btn_id[i];
  var idx = i + 1;
  $(this).addClass(ID + '-' + idx);
```

The rest of the update is just extra non-essential code to build an interactive function and styles for presentation and proof of concept. Details are also commented within the source. I tried to leave no stone unturned (within the limited time I'm giving this answer), and I have extended the original Snippet to aid OP in comprehending what I'm trying convey. Obviously OP has little time for  research and at the moment lacks knowledge of fundamental jQuery/JavaScript. So I advise that OP to actually look at the code, test it, and if it doesn't return the results requested (which both versions do by the way), check the code as it is with and without my code. These examples clearly display that it functions and it's clear that OP's doesn't, so keep that in mind.

***One more thing.*** I added an incremented integer to each class to ensure that there are no duplicates. If that's not a concern and you don't mind having more than one element sharing classes (nothing wrong with that, in fact that's encouraged), you remove this:

```
var idx = i + 1;
```

and remove any portion of code referencing `idx`. This modification will not affect the function's behavior or capabilities to assign a class passed in for each element.

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
// All values of $btn_id in an array
var $btn_id = ['btn', 'btn', 'btn', 'btn', 'any_string_is possible', 'section_first', 'session_2nd', 'part_3', 'etc', 'THIS_IS_THE_CORRECT_WAY'];

/*
| On each iteration through div collection, and
| store the value of $btn_id array at the index of i.
| Add a class to this div, get the string from the
| $btn_id array and concat it to i to ensure each
| new class is unique.
*/
$(".fp_slidesNav").each(function(i) {
  var ID = $btn_id[i];
  var idx = i + 1;
  $(this).addClass(ID + '-' + idx);
});

/*
| This function is for manual testing.
| Enter an arbitrary string, then click 
| the 'add' button.
| Store the value of in1 in a variable.
| Append a div.fp_slidesNav to the end of 
| list.
| Note the new class 'in1' is concat in the
| string of the new div.
*/
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var in1 = $('#in1').val();
  $('body').append('<div class="fp_slidesNav ' + in1 + '"> This element\'s classes are: <\/div>');
});
```

```css
.fp_slidesNav {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
/* 
| Using ':after' '{ content: .attr()' property allows
| us to access attribute values (such as
| class) and display the result as text.
*/

.fp_slidesNav:after {
  content: attr(class);
  color: yellow;
  font: 600 20px/1.5 Verdana;
}
#btn {
  line-height: 1.1;
  width: 48px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#in1 {
  line-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
label {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='btn in1'>
  Class:
  <input id='in1'>
  <button id='btn'>Add</button>
</label>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
<div class="fp_slidesNav">This element's classes are:</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, "btn1, btn2...." are not fixed. it's all what you (users) add. it can be.. "section_first, session_2nd, part_3.." etc.. whatever you want... so I can't use yours.

Comment: You don't see that that's only a string concat to a incremented variable? If you replace the string with a variable (i.e. `$btn`) then it works with whatever value is passed. I assumed you would realize how you were misusing `.each` and now that you know how to properly use the `.each` method you could adapt it to your code. Apparently not, so see the update and if you pay close attention, you'll see that using a ton of repetitive script is costly and pointless. You can can do 1000 repetitive tasks with a few lines using `.each` once. Don't use `.each` as if it was a simple one task function.